# R Shiny - how to make multiple level array in select input?

Tags: r, input, shiny

Can I create a multiple level array on select input in Shiny? How can I achieve it?

This is the code I have in my `ui.R`,

```
# Site 1 options.
selectInput(
    inputId = "site1",
    label = "Select a first site:",
    choices = siteChoices
    ),

# Site 2 options.
selectInput(
    inputId = "site2",
    label = "Select a second site:",
    choices = c('None', siteChoices)
    ),
```

Which creates this html,

```
<select id="site1">
    <option value="9" selected>9  -  Wood Shed</option>
    <option value="13">13  -  V.V.</option>
    <option value="18">18  -  Meryls House</option>
</select>

<select id="site2">
    <option value="None" selected>None</option>
    <option value="13">13  -  V.V.</option>
    <option value="18">18  -  Meryls House</option>
</select>
```

But I want to create this instead,

```
<select id="site1" name="sites[site1]">
    <option value="9" selected>9  -  Wood Shed</option>
    <option value="13">13  -  V.V.</option>
    <option value="18">18  -  Meryls House</option>
</select>

<select id="site2" name="sites[site2]">
    <option value="None" selected>None</option>
    <option value="13">13  -  V.V.</option>
    <option value="18">18  -  Meryls House</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a `name` attribute of your `selectInput`, you can browse a little on the structure returned by `selectInput`. For instance:

```
obj<-selectInput(inputId = "site1",label = "Select a first site:",choices = letters[1:3])
str(obj)
```

By looking at the output of the previous line, you'll see where to enter the `name` attribute:

```
obj$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$attribs$name<-"somename"
obj
#just the relevant part
#<select id="site1" name="somename">
#  <option value="a" selected>a</option>
#  <option value="b">b</option>
#  <option value="c">c</option>
#</select>
```

As you can see, the name has been set. You can define this object outside your `ui` definition and put just `obj` in the right place instead of `selectInput(...)`.

Pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but maybe this can be helpful to get you started.